# Element inserted by JQuery insertbefore won't disappear after navigation in Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor

My purpose is to insert an alert div if an error happened during submission.

```
if error
  # Remove div if already exisits
  if $('.alert').length
    $('.alert').remove()

  warning = "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">#{error.reason}</div>"
  $(warning).insertBefore ".main"
```

However, the alert div won't disappear after any navigation. It would only disappear after I refreshed the page. What happened here? I've tried to use Template to solve this but I still want to know why this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is not normally aware of live DOM updates. jQuery parses when the document is ready or upon some predefined events for the contents of the DOM at the time of the event. But when page gets updated outside the scope of jQuery, it loses track of the DOM.

For that, jQuery even had an additional [`live()` API](https://api.jquery.com/live/) and more recently delegated events of the [`on()` API](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Or, you can make use of a dedicated plugin that solves this problem, such as [Livequery](http://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/)

In Meteor, you should not be adding/removing DOM elements externally like that. For that purpose, you have [declared templates, or the template API](http://docs.meteor.com/#templates)

In your case, you could just as easily defined a boolean template helper and used {{#if}} handlebars block to check the condition to display/hide the error div if the error is a generic one. Or if it is a custom error, then you can register that as a helper.

```
<template name="errorDisplay">
  <div class="alert alert-danger">{errorMessage}</div>
</template>
```

and on your js

```
Template.errorDisplay.helpers({
  errorMessage: function() {
    return error && error.message;
  }
})
```

or with a boolean block you could do

```
<template name="errorDisplay">
  {{#if hasError}}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">There is an error!</div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

and on your js

```
Template.errorDisplay.helpers({
  hasError: function() {
    return error && true;
  }
})
```

Comment: It's a little bit confusing about the scope for Meteor templates so I used a registerHelper to do that. Then where should I declare the error flag for the {{#if}} statement for the template?

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect a template scoped helper. You can of course always register a global helper, but scoping is better since templates have instances and contexts which you can further utilize.